# Favorite Questions and Answers from fourth quarter of 2017

Tags: discussion, blog

### Update

The article has now been posted.

[Highlights from 2017 – 4th Quarter](https://thesffblog.com/2018/01/highlights-from-2017-4th-quarter/)

---

Please link to your favorite questions and answers which were either asked or answered from October 1st 2017 through December 31 2017 (**They don't have to be *your* questions and answers, but it also doesn't matter if you want to self promote your own stuff.**).

Your answers will be compiled into a blog post like previous [quarterly posts](https://thesffblog.com/category/qotw/).

I will be using DavRob60's queries for a baseline, but I really appreciate people voicing the ones they really enjoyed. Maybe you feel like you answered one really well, even if it didn't receive a lot of votes. Let me know about it.

- [Questions with most **Votes** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106579/questions-with-most-votes-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2017/10/01)
- [Questions with most **View** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106705/questions-with-most-view-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2017/10/01)
- [Questions with **best answer** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106709/questions-with-best-answer-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2017/10/01)

**I will also be linking all blog posts that happened within this quarter.**

Also if there was a meta post you feel should be spotlighted those are also acceptable.

### I would like to go on record that there are no cats in America, and the streets are paved with cheese.

Answer (score 4):

### **Favorite Quesion**

> @DisturbedNeo's question about the [Origin of Shark Repellent](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/175225/75000) was very interesting, and @FuzzyBoots' [response](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/175227/75000) was surprising and educational. I did not expect such a thing to be

...

> based on something in real life.

### **Favorite Answer**

> My Lady @Bellatrix's [answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/172069/75000) to my question about [Transfiguration and Animagi](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/172059/75000) was very detailed and well thought out. It was also the only one to directly answer my question **right at the top**, which made it convenient and was appreciated.

### **Honorable Mention**

> @jpmc26's [MIB question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/175356/75000) and [the](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/175360/75000) [top](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/175363/75000) [answers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/175365/75000) put up good arguments and were very fun to read.

Comment: I’m so glad you liked my answer enough to nominate it! :D

Comment: @Bellatrix And it wasn't simply because you're my Mistress. Honest. ;D

Comment: I’m honored! ;)

Answer (score 3):

**blows own horn**

I'm rather proud of [this self-answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/176307/33591) that I wrote to my question [Was the mythology in "Moana" based on an established myth?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/176188/33591). I spent over 4 hours researching this answer, and learned more about Polynesian mythology than I ever thought I'd know. I wasn't expecting to write a self-answer when I wrote the question, but I thought I'd take a shot at it after seeing it go HNQ. It also conveniently gave me a few hats for Winter Bash 2017 :D

Comment: Didn’t take you to the top though *\*also blows own horn**

Comment: Nice one. Liked your answer better than the actual movie, which i quit after 20 min.

Answer (score 3):

### Question

I'm going to go with Loki's question "[Why did the Voyager Doctor have to scrub in?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/170842/why-did-the-voyager-doctor-have-to-scrub-in)", largely because it's asking about an event that looks like a simple writing error but that turned out to be *incredibly subtle foreshadowing*.

### Answer

Tooting one's own trumpet, I'm going to say that my answer to "[Is Luke Skywalker actually a Jedi?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/171610/is-luke-skywalker-actually-a-jedi)" was one that I enjoyed writing. It's a deceptively simple question but one that deserved a proper answer. This is also the poster-child for my contention that if something's worth doing, it's *[worth doing with massive overkill](https://media.giphy.com/media/NfcfXZ8g2pLmo/giphy.gif)*